# how to fix /login_check "this page isn't working" on hosted symfony 3.4 project

Tags: php, yaml, symfony-3.4

i created this website and used FOS_user bundle as user Manager, while developing the application everything worked fine, i can log in and register and everything on local machine using wampserver, but when i uploaded it to a hosting server the problem started, i can login on admin.domain on both dev and prod environments but not on www.domain, i get www.domain/login_check and "this page isn't working" any help will be appreciated

security.yml

security:

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        user_checker: security.user_checker
        form_login:
            provider:             fos_userbundle
            login_path:           fos_user_security_login
            check_path:           fos_user_security_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # default_target_path: homepage 
            # always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:        fos_user_security_logout
            target:      homepage
        anonymous: true
        http_basic: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/ar/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/en/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/fr/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: could you provide server configuration? Consider the following instruction https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: thank you for your response, indeed it's a server configuration issue, but they(internet agency) will solve it because it's a government website.

Answer (score 1):

after 3 days of trying to figure this out and after trying every possible solution turns out it's a server problem, they needed to add permission to access user table from www.domain